# Python looking through a list effectively

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently working on an exam project in python, where I have to make a choropleth map that shows all the different countries in the world, and what their populations are.

I get my data from an api and store that data in 2 different lists, let's call them a and b.

a contains values looking like this:

```
a = [['Afghanistan', 'AF'], ['Åland Islands', 'AX'], ['Albania', 'AL'], ['Algeria', 'DZ'], ['American Samoa', 'AS'], ['Andorra', 'AD'], ['Angola', 'AO']
```

and b:

```
b = ['Afghanistan' 'AFRICA' 'Albania' 'Algeria' 'Angola'
```

I want to create a new list named c that contains only the values, which appears
in BOTH lists.

What confuses me the most, is that, "a" contains both country names and 
country codes, and "b" contains single values, listed next to each other.

list "c" should end up looking something like this: ['Afghanistan','Albania',Algeria','Angola']...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can flatten the first list using [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) and use [set intersection](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection):

```
>>> set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(a)) & set(b)
set(['Afghanistan', 'Albania', 'Angola', 'Algeria'])
```

If you don't want the itertools import (at the cost of a bit of performance):

```
>>> set([i for j in a for i in j]) & set(b)
set(['Afghanistan', 'Albania', 'Angola', 'Algeria'])
```

Comment: A suggestion: No need for direct flattening, `a` can be turned directly and efficiently into a `dict` and then you can use `dict.keys()` as the first set.

Comment: But what if there are intersections in the second element?

Comment: It it shouldn't matter in this use case, at least not from what the OP is describing.

Comment: My timings are showing that as slower than `chain.from_iterable`

Comment: `In [14]: %timeit set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(a)) & set(b)
1.29 µs ± 6.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)`

Comment: `In [17]: %timeit set(dict(a).keys()) & set(b)
1.82 µs ± 18.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)`

Comment: This answer relies on the fact that the country names and codes never intersect.  While that's almost certainly true in practice, forming a mixed-semantic-type set feels a little clunky.

Comment: Possible new entry for [Falsehoods Programmers Believe](https://github.com/kdeldycke/awesome-falsehood): "A country code is never the same string as the name of a country"?

Comment: You can write `set(country for (country, code) in a)` instead of `set([i for j in a for i in j])` to get rid of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

i too new to python and i dont know the predefined functions and i write my logic to you. Hope this work for you ...

```
a = [['Afghanistan', 'AF'], ['Åland Islands', 'AX'], ['Albania', 'AL'], ['Algeria', 'DZ'], ['American Samoa', 'AS'], ['Andorra', 'AD'], ['Angola', 'AO']]

    b = ['Afghanistan' ,'AFRICA', 'Albania' ,'Algeria', 'Angola']

    c=[]
    for i in range(0,len(b)):
        for j in range(0,len(a)):
            if(b[i]==a[j][0]):
                c.append(b[i])
                break        
    print(c)
```

have fun in python